# How to use Stored Procedure with Mule 3.5 Batch Processing

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, hashmap, mule, batch-processing

I am using Mule 3.5 Anypoint connector and have moved from a select query to a stored procedures in the batch processing scope component. With that change mule does not like the object type that the stored procedure returns.

Here is the error that I get back:

```
ERROR 2014-06-26 15:15:00,426 [pool-15-thread-1] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Object "java.util.HashMap" not of correct type. It must be of type "{interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection}" (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The type of object returned from the database connector using a stored procedure is as such:

```
java.util.HashMap
```

With the `Select` statement (this works) the type is as such:

```
org.mule.util.CaseInsensitiveHashMap
```

Like stated above with the select statement this does work.

Some extra information about the system:

- It is SQL Server 2008 R2
- The database connector works fine with the stored procedure but errors when it reaches the process records section

  ```
  <batch:job name="ons-esb-mainBatch1">
  <batch:threading-profile poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
  <batch:input>
      <poll doc:name="Poll">
          <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="15" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
          <db:stored-procedure config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
              <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{ CALL otis.GetEntityQueueByTime() }]]></db:parameterized-query>
          </db:stored-procedure>
      </poll>
      <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
  </batch:input>
  <batch:process-records>
      <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
          <choice doc:name="Choice">
              <!-- Choice Selector Logic -- Taken Out to Save Space --!>
          </choice>
      </batch:step>
  </batch:process-records>
  <batch:on-complete>
      <logger message="EntityQueues Completed Queueing into ActiveMQ" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
  </batch:on-complete>
  ```

Summary

I would like to find a way to have the object be processed through the batch process will work as a select statement would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `java.util.HashMap` is not iterable. Try replacing the message payload with its `entrySet()`:

`<batch:input>
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
        <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="15" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
        <db:stored-procedure config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{ CALL otis.GetEntityQueueByTime() }]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:stored-procedure>
    </poll>
    <set-payload value="#[message.payload.entrySet()]" />
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</batch:input>`